# JPQL IN clause with @Convert

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

In non normalized PostgreSQL database: Two tables "Document" and "Record"

**Document** has an id, and a comma-separated column recodeIds

```
--------------------------------------
| id (VARCHAR) | recordIds (VARCHAR) |
--------------------------------------
| 1            | 3,1                 |
| 2            | 2                   |
--------------------------------------
```

**Record** has id and name

```
---------------------------------
| id (VARCHAR) | name (VARCHAR) |
---------------------------------
| 1            | X              |
| 2            | Y              |
| 3            | Z              |
---------------------------------
```

**DocumentModel** with @Convert

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Document")
public class DocumentModel {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "recodeIds")
    @Convert(converter = RecordsConverter.class)
    private Set<String> records;
}
```

**RecordsConverter**

```
public class RecordsConverter implements AttributeConverter<Set<String>, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Set<String> recordTypes) {
        return String.join(",", recordTypes);
    }
    @Override
    public Set<String> convertToEntityAttribute(String recordTypes) {
        return Arrays.stream(recordTypes.split(",")).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

**JPQL** Now I'm trying to use records in @Query

```
@Query("SELECT D.id, R.name)"
    + " FROM DocumentModel D"
    + " JOIN RecordModel R"
    + " ON R.id IN D.records"
    + " WHERE D.id = :docId"
```

This only works if **recordIds** has single value (Example: docId = 2)

It's not working if **recordIds** has multiple values (Example: docId = 1) even if:

- Nested SELECT not working
- IN clause with and without () not working
- MEMBER OF clause not working
- Resulted native SQL directly not working
- @Formula not working

And it seems the problem is that records should be **single-quoted-comma-separated** and not only **comma-separated** as they are strings. (Native SQL query works in this case)

**Q:** How to make this work using JPQL (non native query) without changing the RecordsConverter, and hopefully without JPA Specifications?

Comment: The best way to solve this problem, is to normalize your data model. Storing comma separated values in a single column is a huge mistake to begin with

Comment: You're right, but the customer refused :/

Comment: @AhmedGhoneim Does it work in the sql query analog of your JPQL?

Comment: No. It works only with single-quoted-comma-separated values

Comment: You could create a view that presents a normalized version of the `document` table. Then you use a regular join to combine that with the `Record` table

Comment: Cannot change db. "Customer Requirement"

Comment: Seems like I'm also affected by https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11803

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I was affected by [Hibernate bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11803)

As a workaround, use collection wrappers:

```
@Data
@Builder
public class MyCollection implements Serializable {
    private final Set<String> collection;
}
```

and change your Attribute Converter:

```
public class MyConverter implements AttributeConverter<MyCollection, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(MyCollection myCollection) {
        return String.join(",", myCollection.getCollection());
    }
    @Override
    public MyCollection convertToEntityAttribute(String myCollection) {
        return MyCollection.builder()
                .collection(Arrays.stream(myCollection.split(",")).collect(Collectors.toSet()))
                .build();
    }
}
```

and you Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_MODEL")
public class MyModel {
    @Column(name = "MY_COLLECTION")
    @Convert(converter = MyConverter.class)
    private MyCollection myCollection;
}
```

That worked for me.